# Rails match routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to generate an unsubscribe link that a person can click on in an email. Here's what my route looks like:

```
match "/unsubscribe/:email/:token" => "mailing_list_recipients#destroy", :as => :unsubscribe
```

When I run `rake routes`, I get:

```
unsubscribe GET /unsubscribe/:email/:token(.:format) mailing_list_recipients#destroy
```

I can even do:

```
unsubscribe_url(mailing_list_recipient.email, mailing_list_recipient.token)
```

which outputs:

```
http://localhost:3000/unsubscribe/hello@hello.com/f99e3af9bd959c6c8f3882a6e10e354e
```

However, when I try to visit this URL, I get the following error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/unsubscribe/schroppl@gmail.com/6458f6a714d81a9cdd1cd1133dd65f0d"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you should url encode the email address

Comment: You were right @apneadiving. Can you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in comment, you should simply url encode the email address

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the **point** of the email address: schroppl@gmail.com.

You have to write adapters. Replace point with another symbol, like "!" (if you still want email in URL string):

Code could be something like that:

```
# Recipient:

def email_for_url
  email.gsub(/\./,"!")
end

def self.search_by_email(url_email)
  find_by_email(url_email.gsub(/\!/,"."))
end
```

So you can use:

```
unsubscribe_url(mailing_list_recipient.email_for_url, mailing_list_recipient.token)

Recipient.search_by_email(params[:email])
```

Comment: I feel like URL encoding the email address is an bit easier and guarantees it can be passed through the URL.

Comment: Well, encoding the email is killing the idea itself - to show _recognizable_ (by human eye) email in URL. Otherwise you could use any another ID.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the email address, which you can do in any number of ways.

```
# ERB in your view
<%=u unsubscribe_url(mailing_list_recipient.email, mailing_list_recipient.token) %>

# Using Rack::Utils
Rack::Utils.escape(unsubscribe_url(mailing_list_recipient.email, mailing_list_recipient.token))

# Using URI::escape
URI::escape(unsubscribe_url(mailing_list_recipient.email, mailing_list_recipient.token))
```

This will change your URL from

```
http://localhost:3000/unsubscribe/hello@hello.com/f99e3af9bd959c6c8f3882a6e10e354e
```

to

```
http://localhost:3000/unsubscribe/hello%40hello.com/f99e3af9bd959c6c8f3882a6e10e354e
```